# Computing the variance of $Y$ given $Y_i=a+bX_i+u_i$, where the distribution of $u_i$ is known

Tags: probability, proof-verification, regression

I'm working on the following problem, which I quote verbatim from the assignment.

> Suppose that in the regression equation
>   $$Y_i=a+bX_i+u_i$$
>   the coefficients are $a=1$ and $b=2$. Suppose also the probability distribution of $u$ is discrete, equaling $-5$ with probability $1/4$, $0$ with probability $1/2$, and $5$ with probability $1/4$. Calculate the expected value and the variance of $Y_i$ when $X_i=4$. How does the variance of $Y$ compare with the variance of $u$?

Computing $E[Y_i | X_i=4]$ is easy:

$$E[Y_i | X_i=4] = E[1+2X_i+u_i | X_i=4] = E[1|X_i=4] + 2E[X_i|X_i=4]+E[u_i|X_i=4]$$

The first term is $1$, and the second term is $2(4)$. For the last term, I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to argue that by mean independence between $u$ and $X$ we have $E[u_i|X_i=4]=E[u_i]$, or whether I should just pretend the problem gives me not the unconditional distribution of $u$ but the conditional distribution of $u$. Either way, the last term is zero. Thus the expected value of $Y_i$ given $X_i=4$ is $9$.

I also know that
$$\text{Var}(Y_i|X_i=4)=\text{Var}(1+2X_i+u_i|X_i=4)=\text{Var}(u_i|X_i=4)$$
because $1+2X_i$ is a constant, conditional on $X_i=4$, and adding a constant to a random variable makes no difference to the variance. Again assuming $\text{Var}(u_i|X_i=4)=\text{Var}(u_i)$, we just calculate $E[u_i^2]-E[u_i]^2=12.5-0=12.5$.

My problem is with the last question: "how does the variance of $Y$ compare with the variance of $u$?" For "the variance of $Y$," should I use the conditional variance I just calculated? Or does this mean I should now calculate the *unconditional* variance of $Y$?

I can try to find the unconditional variance using the law of total variance:

$$\text{Var}(Y)=E[\text{Var}(Y|X)]+\text{Var}(E[Y|X])$$

The first term is $E[12.5]=12.5$, as I calculated above. But the second term is $\text{Var}(1+2X)=4\text{Var}(X)$, and I don't know enough about $X$ to calculate this variance.

Comment: We know nothing about $X$? (For example I would often see $X$ being a known Gaussian.) Also, you haven't calculated $\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)$ but rather $\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X=4)$. I don't think there is a special simplification for $\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)$ with the given information.

Comment: If the last question is meant to be answered with numbers, then you must assume it's talking about $Var(Y|X=4)$, since that's the only "variance of $Y$" that you can calculate; in this case it equals $Var(u)$.  If the last question is a "general discussion" question, then I think you might say e.g. assuming $X, u$ independent we have $Var(Y) = Var(X) + Var(u) \ge Var(u)$.  From just the wording... I'm not sure what is meant.